# Jquery ui date picker previous month instead of the next

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

My problem is that at the second click on input (to) the calendar displays the following month.

For example, on the first click on input (to) the calendar displays Jan and Feb (that's what i want). If I select a date in Jan, there is no problem. But 
1-if I select a date in Feb, the calendar displays Feb and Mar and not Jan and Feb.
2-if I select a date in march, the calendar displays march and april and not feb and march... etc

https://jsfiddle.net/aminos12/vty1qk7f/

```
var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $( "#from" )
        .datepicker({
          numberOfMonths: 2
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });

    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }

      return date;
```

[image]
jQuery UI version - v1.12.1 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behaviour of `datepicker` when you set to show multiple months. If you change the behaviour, you might face a problem of not showing the right `month` for the first time or people getting annoyed having have to click on next month arrow when it comes to selecting a date in future and open the `datepicker` again.

It would be very important especially for websites like travel agencies when you want to choose from and to dates.

A better option is to show the `Today` button at the bottom of it for ease of use if they have chosen a date in future and then want to go back to the initial two months or selecting today.

This is done useing `showButtonPanel: true` in options.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display multiple months</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      showButtonPanel: true
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker by default does not do this.

If I understand your question correctly, you want the 2 months to always be this month and next month.  If I select a date in February for "from", then when I click in the "to" field, you still want to see Jan-Feb, is that correct?  That's how Datepicker works by default.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/zk8ou5k4/2/)

```
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
});
$( "#to" ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
});
```

[image: screenshot of working JSFiddle]

[minDate and maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) set the min/max *selectable* dates, not the min/max displayed dates.  If you set minDate to 1st Jan, it just means you can't select 31st Dec.  To actually shift which months are shown, use [showCurrentAtPos](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showCurrentAtPos).  If you are displaying 2 months, set `showCurrentAtPos: 0` to show the current month at position 0 (the first of the 2).  Note that this example is meaningless since this is the default behaviour!

Comment: @mino did this help?